# Is Inverse of bijective morphism also morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, morphism

Let $V_1,V_2$ be affine varieties.
Let $f$ be a morphism(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_algebraic_varieties) between $V_1,V_2$.

If $f$ is bijective, is inver of $f$ also morphism ?
If not, I would be appreciated if you could've me some examples.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is true if $V_2$ is normal (eg non-singular) and the field is of characteristic $0$, by Zariski's main theorem. See the first answer of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73321/isomorphism-between-varieties-of-char-0/73348#73348 In Sasha's example, the target is not normal, because it has a singularity at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The simplest example is the morphism
$$
\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbbk[t]) \to \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbbk[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3)),
\qquad 
x = t^2,\ y = t^3.
$$